# XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest data-hub-STAGING-1 not available: middle closing

Tags: marklogic, mlcp

I am ingesting a 100+ mb document in Marklogic through datahub framework and timeout occurs while execution of mlcp commend.

During my investigation, I found below logs in errors_log file.

Info: invalidating cache: debugging-enabled 
Notice: XDMP-FORESTNOT: Forest data-hub-STAGING-1 not available: middle closing 
Notice:+in /MarkLogic/rest-api/endpoints/resource-service-query.xqy [1.0-ml]

I tried multiple configuration changes but no luck. Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Marklogic Version : 9.0-2

Answer (score 0):

Btw did you resolve this? I've seen this also when I've tried to clear the staging db while another operation is occurring. It should resolve itself.

FYI when a forest is in a "middle closing", it indicates that the forest is waiting for all references to its stands to be released.  It will transfer to the "finishClosing" state after that. So you may still have some on-going transactions which is preventing it from closing.